# @autowired does not work on struts2 + spring

Tags: java, spring, struts2, autowired, struts2-spring-plugin

I want to make a web application based on struts2 and spring.  First of all, I tested if @Autowired does work on struts2. But it does not, dataSource is null. I have no idea how I can fix it. Please give me an infomation for it.

HelloWorld.java

```
package example;
import java.sql.Connection;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
@Component
public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {
    @Autowired
    private BasicDataSource dataSource;
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
        con.close();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="example" />
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="example" namespace="/example" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="HelloWorld" class="example.test.HelloWorld">
        <result>/example/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: The only time a `@Autowired` target can be `null` is if Spring is not managing the object. Look into sprint-struts integration bridge. Right now Struts is creating the object, not Spring.

Comment: To use `DI`, you need to do as below: 1.write a correct JDBC properties; 2.entity class; 3. register those entity or component into `applicationContext.xml`.  please check!  seems you did not have register them into `xml`, please do the registration or use `package scan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `@Autowired` work in your struts application you need to the given things:

Make sure you have the struts2 and spring plugin in your classpath.

Put the following line in `strtus.xml`

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />
  ... 
</struts>
```

Configure the `Action classes` in xml file of spring

```
<bean id="editAction" class="org.apache.struts.edit.action.EditAction" >

    <property name="editService" ref="editService" />

</bean>
```

And give the bean id in `struts.xml` file instead of giving the action class

```
<action name="edit" class="editAction" method="input">
    <result name="input">/edit.jsp</result>
</action>
```

For more information consult http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/spring-and-struts-2.html and http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/spring-plugin.html

Comment: thank you very much. in according with your anwer i modified my code and i added "setDataSource" in action class, finally my code does work.

Comment: @Autowired is working for me with below configurations:

struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire=no in struts.properties file 
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" /> in strits.xml